# Как реализовать отслеживание изменения обьекта?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Задача:
Получаю xml из внешнего API. Демаршалю его в цепочку наследованных объектов. Работаю с этими объектами. На определенном этапе мне необходимо проверить в каких объектах были произведены изменения, и отослать обратно в апи xml только из измененных объектов.

Какие идеи пришли в голову:
Работать с хэшкодом - сохранять хэши объектов на момент их генерации из xml. А перед отправкой снова брать хэш объектов, и сверять изменился ли он. Но пока вижу проблему, что если изменится хэш дочернего объекта, то хэш родителя тоже поменяется, и в итоге я обратно закину все дерево наследованных объектов.

Делать какой то маркер обьекта. Если в одном из полей обьектов сетится новое значение, то менять маркер на true. В таком случае есть универсальный способ или шаблон для реализации данной идеи? Хардкодить все это во всех сеттрерах кажется плохой идеей

Вопрос: 
Как лучше отслеживать изменения обьектов? Может кто то поделиться своим опытом или ссылкой?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491915/java-api-which-can-idenetify-the-difference-between-two-xml-files

Comment: использовать AOP. подвесить аспект на изменяющие состояния объектов методы. При их вызове добавлять объект в коллекцию измененных объектов. Есть вариант, сделать тоже самое но через паттерн декоратор.

Comment: Как вариант - сделать объекты иммутабельными и после модификаций сранивать их через == с исходными.

Answer (score 1):

На паттерн не тянет, конечно, но рецепт годный:

В моем случае был набор JSON/XML объектов, которые транслировались в *Java beans*, которые отображались на UI. При переходе в режим редактирования на UI вываливалась копия Java объекта и после возвращения из редактирования я тупо сравнивал копию после редакции и до редакции в случае отличия выставлялся флажок `isChanged()`, далее все объекты `isChanged()==true` писались в БД уже в виде XML/JSON.

Попытка реализации всей этой истории слушателями по-моему полезна если мало полей, а если количество полей превышает хотя бы десяток, то замучаешься ставить слушатели на каждое поле или писать сильно умный слушатель который отслеживает изменения. К тому же даже наличие слушателя не сильно спасет, потому что юзер может обратно вернуть исправления - так что по факту выходной объект не будет отличаться от исходного.

Смысл в том, что изменения объектов ловить лучше в Java бинах, а не на уровне XML/JSON объектов.

Как то так.